# Why does my Word Cloud still have 2 words phrases?

Tags: text, word-cloud, orange

I am currently trying to do word cloud for the review of a product. however, when i followed the template, i encountered 2-word phrases in it. is this normal or how do i correct this? This may be due to Orange's lack of Malaysian language, which is the review's language. However, i have tried the Indonesian option and it still occurs.

[This is the orange flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzbVv.png)

[The preprocess widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbti9.png)

[the final word cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQwba.png)

also, [is this meta role normal?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5MfQ.png). i also need to do sentiment analysis after this, but it requires a target role